# Goat-friendly evergreen hedge plants on Iberian Peninsula

Tags: shrubs, hedge, evergreens

Am starting a goat and sheep farm in the drier parts on the Iberian Peninsula and would like to have a hedge dividing different parts of the land plot. In my search I came across the plant [Portugal Laurel (*Prunus lusitanica ‘Angustifolia’*)](https://www.gardenersworld.com/how-to/grow-plants/portuguese-laurel-hedge/) which makes a nice, dense, evergreen and easy-maintenance hedge. However, this plant is [toxic](https://goatsauthority.com/can-goats-eat-laurel-leaves/) to goats as the plant produces hydrocyanic acid. Knowing goats, they will likely eat it.

My question is: what goat- and sheep-friendly hedge plants can I choose that:

1. are evergreen,
2. make a dense hedge,
3. tolerate drier soils,
4. are easy to prune, and
5. are common on the peninsula?

Comment: Aren't the goats and sheep just going to eat whatever hedge you plant?  I mean ho is it going to grow?

Comment: There will be movable fenced enclosures. After a couple of years the goats would have an all-you-can-eat hedge, hopefully it will grow faster than they can browse on it. Sheep only graze, not browse.

Answer (score 2):

Goats avoid [strong-flavored plants](https://animals.mom.com/what-weeds-dont-goats-eat-12534945.html) such as **sage** and **lavender**. Sheep and deer will, too.

You know how well these herbs grow in Provence and throughout the Mediterranean.

- **Rosemary**, aromatic and Mediterranean, would seem to fit this category.
- **Moroccan Nana** is a menthol spearmint and grows throughout North Africa to Middle East.
- **Hydrangea** - Alkaline soil will give you pink flowers, not blue, unless you copper-acidify the soil. I wouldn't.
- **Oregon Grape Holly** (a 6' Barberry shrub):

[image: pic of Oregon Grape Holly]

Of course, grazing animals don't like the onion family (alliums) - daffodils included.